# Creating a dropdown menu from an array and prepend the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I will use for a dropdown in a form. My array is something like this...

```
$data = ('1' => 'Option 1', '2' => 'Option 2', '3' => 'Options 3')
```

Now I want to prepend this to the $data array

```
'' => 'Please select'
```

How do I do this? I've tried array_unshift but this adds a key to my option which I don't want because of my form validation.

Anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the dropdown, think it will always create a numeric key when using an array. Could try hardcode the first option in between your select tags?

Comment: [`array_push`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) pushes variable to the end of the array, but it will associate value with next index kex. You cannot have identical keys in your array; so you need to approach this problem with different method.

Answer (score 0):

All array values have a key. array_shift is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [union operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$data = ('1' => 'Option 1', '2' => 'Option 2', '3' => 'Options 3')
$prependArray = array('' => 'Please select');
$result = $prependArray + $data;
```